# Changing JTable cell color

Tags: java, swing, formatting, rendering, jtable

This is driving me absolutely insane.

I know that, to change the formatting of table cells with JTable, I have to use my own renderer. But I cannot seem to implement this properly.

This is my current setup:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JTable myTable = new JTable(10, 10);
        myTable.setDefaultRenderer ([I dont know what to put here], new CustomRenderer());
    }
}

class CustomRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer 
{
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        // Formatting
        return c;
    }
}
```

What do I need to use for the first parameter of `setDefaultRenderer`? The API just says 'class'. I have no idea what to put there.

Could someone just explain, in the simplest of terms, how I go about implementing this? Please provide an example of how I can change the formatting from within the `main()` method as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the first parameter for `setDefaultRenderer`, put the **class literal** for the Class that you want to override rendering. I.e., if your data consist all of strings, you can put

```
myTable.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new CustomRenderer());
```

If your data also consists of values with `BigDecimal` or `Integer` as classes, you have to invoke that method several times for each class type (`BigDecimal.class` or `Integer.class` in each case).

And finally, to change the background color you do this in your renderer:

```
class CustomRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer 
{
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 72, 72));
        return c;
    }
}
```

If you write a renderer that should work for **all classes of an interface**, you will also need to modify the `getColumnClass` function of your **table model** and let it return the interface class for all objects that implement this interface:

```
public Class<? extends Object> getColumnClass(int c) {
    Object object = getValueAt(0, c);
    if(object == null) {
        return Object.class;
    if(getValueAt(0, c) instanceof IColorable) {
        return ICarPart.class;
    } else {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }
}
```

With that one can register a renderer for IColorable.class and does not need to register a separate renderer for each implementation.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. The only thing I've done is invoke the setDefaultRenderer method and created the CustomRenderer class. Is there something else I need to be doing to get this to work?

Comment: I got it working by using Object.class instead of String.class. Not sure why this was necessary, though, because all of my data were strings.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Am I not allowed to change the renderer inside a listener? I want to re-format the table when a button is pressed.

Comment: You need to use Object.class because you created a JTable w/o passing in a TableModel. The default table model created returns Object.class for each columns type. See: TableModel::getColumnClass(int col)

Comment: Where do I use it? Say I now want to change a table cell's colour when I click on it?