# JTable, JTextArea or JEditorPane to highlight lines of code?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextcomponent

### Update:

I've found a partial solution in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/818313/196834), by adding the following code:

```
class CustomRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer 
{
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 72, 72));
        return c;
    }
}
```

And then passing it to my JTable object:

```
jTable2.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new CustomRenderer());
```

This works correctly and now the table rows are coloured red:

[image: Psuedocode Panel]

**The only thing I need to know now is how to restrict the colouring to a single row and a single cell.**

After further research I need a `setCellRender()` method so that I can set the custom render on a particular cell, but this method doesn't exist.

---

### Question:

I want to create a visual component of step-by-step pseudocode execution.

To do this I have created a JTable and now I am looking for ways to highlight each row (or cell since there is only one column) to display which line is being executed.

I've included a mockup below on the final GUI. As you can see in the Pseudocode panel I've highlighted the final row.

**Please ignore the arrows they are not strictly related to the question.**

[image: Wireframe]

I've started to implement the mockup in Netbeans Matisse (this is 1 of 3 algorithms). However I don't know how to highlight the single line `code line 1` in the JTable component.

Would it be easier to use a different type of component?

Later I'll also need to be able to re-color individual cells as show in the mockup's Table JPanel. How can this be implemented?

[image: Partial implementation]

Comment: _I can set the custom render on a particular cell_ - no that's not what you need :-) Instead, you need a custom renderer which decides about the visuals of its rendering component based on the parameters passed into the getXXCellRendererComponent, see f.i. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: I see. So I set the custom renderer to all cells and then check which cell needs highlighting within the custom renderer method? I still don't know how to check what cell I am in within the custom renderer method.

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand ;-) The parameters of the method tell you all you need to know. You did read the tutorial I linked to above, didn't you?

Comment: If I do a condition statement in my `getTableCellRendererComponent` method - `if(column == 0 && row == 1)
            c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 72, 72));` it still paints all cells red.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) use [JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) for supporting styled text, there you have three choices

- use `HighLighter`
- use `Html` formatted text (Java6 in current form supporting <= `Html3.2` and with reduced supporting of css, sure in compare with `Html5`)
- combine both a.m. options together
- write own EditorKit or HtmlEditorKit (thanks to @stryba)

2) for [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) pass desired value to the `prepareRenderer()` rather than implement `getTableCellRendererComponent()`

3) if value for [JSlider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) is modifiable (from another JComponents) then look for `BoundedRangeModel`

Comment: Just to add one more possible to point 1) you can also create your own `EditorKit` with its own `View`, which is a more work but usually outperforms the other options

Comment: @stryba thank you for notice, hmmm for all EditorKit or HtmlEditorKit rellated questions is there our (JTextComponent's King @StanislavL),

Comment: -1 for 2) (time to start a quest against that spreading not quite correct advice :-) that's _not_ the general way to achieve visual cell decorations in application code, instead custom renderers are. The basic rule is: never-ever extend a JSomething for application needs, they are meant to be used as-is. That said: extending core components with additional functionality (in this context f.i. add api to allow custom striping) is fine: this allows to re-use the extended component without _further_ extension in all your applications, they can configure the custom component as appropriate.

Comment: This answer and the comment above have left me slightly confused. I assume that I should extend JTable in a custom class and ?override? the `prepareRenderer()` method. I should confess also that I am not very well experience with Java Swing.

Comment: 1) maybe would be better waiting for @kleopatra's reply, 2) this comment is about `pass desired value` and be sure basically her honesty have got true, and more than valuable, in the case that you know something about Swing, 3) I have to notice this not possible to answering your question without edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), 4) I take this question as interview only,

Comment: hmmm... as often as I read the bullets in your comment, I can't make much sense out of them, except the part about the SSCCE :-)

Answer (score 2):

A small code for your help, how to achieve highlighting specific text literal with desired background on JTextPane :

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.border.*;

import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;

public class TextPaneTest extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JTextPane tPane;

    public TextPaneTest()
    {
        topPanel = new JPanel();        

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);            

        EmptyBorder eb = new EmptyBorder(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

        tPane = new JTextPane();                
        tPane.setBorder(eb);
        //tPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
        tPane.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

        topPanel.add(tPane);

        appendToPane(tPane, "My Name is Too Good.\n", Color.RED, Color.YELLOW);
        appendToPane(tPane, "I wish I could be ONE of THE BEST on ", Color.BLUE, Color.WHITE);
        appendToPane(tPane, "Stack", Color.PINK, Color.WHITE);
        appendToPane(tPane, "Over", Color.YELLOW, Color.RED.brighter());
        appendToPane(tPane, "flow", Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN.darker());

        getContentPane().add(topPanel);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);   
    }

    private void appendToPane(JTextPane tp, String msg, Color c, Color bColor)
    {
        StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
        AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, c);

        aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.Background, bColor);
        //  aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, c);

        aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Lucida Console");
        aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.Alignment, StyleConstants.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);

        int len = tp.getDocument().getLength();
        tp.setCaretPosition(len);
        tp.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
        tp.replaceSelection(msg);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    new TextPaneTest();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Here is the output :

[image: JTEXTPANE TEXT HIGHLIGHTING]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although that addresses another issue I have in the `Calculations Area` it still doesn't address the problem I am having with colouring JTable cells.

Comment: @Ash : Ahhh... Wish I could help you on `JTable` s, but my knowledge in them is way too short. I am sorry about that. But hoping this answer might help you somewhere in your endeavour and hopefully you might find your answer soon :-)