# Set backgrond color for a cell in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing JTable cell color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818287/changing-jtable-cell-color)

I have to set the color of some specific cells in jtable but when i write the following code the whole table is colored

```
Component cell=(Component) jTable2.getCellRenderer(0,0);
                cell.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```

In this case only (0,0) should be colored.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet did not get you.

Comment: how about doing at least a _bit_ of research on the topic? Starting with the Swing tutorial referenced in the swing tag wiki, particularly [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and going on with the references to earlier related questions, listed in the sidebar?

Comment: You've basically grabbed the default renderer for all the cells and changed the color that it should use to render all the cells. Check out the like Guilluame provided for more information